# git ignoring file after setting -assume--unchanged and deletion

Tags: github

I have done something ridiculous with git out of sheer laziness and now do not know which way to turn. I have a file:

```
 www/include/global.inc.
```

Initially I had set this file to ignore using the command

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged www/include/global.inc
```

Later, I found that there were indeed several changes to be made by several people in the file and I cannot ignore it like that. So I used the command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged www/include/global.inc
```

to remove the ignore.

After that, I had some problems and when someone else had done a change in the file I found that I was unable to pull the file to my local system as git reported an error. So I deleted the file from my end and then did a pull and it worked and I got the file.

Now I am making a change in the same file and I need to push it into the repository.

And the git status command will not report it as modified. I have tried the same trick of deleting it from the directory www/include/ and trying to pull it freshly but git says 'Already up to date'. I tried the `-assume--unchanged` command again and that also does not work. I am at my wits end trying to find a solution and I need to push that file in before today.

If I put the file in some other folder then it gets reported as an untracked file. I have checked my `.gitignore` file and there is nothing to indicate that it is being ignored by something there.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to clone again your repo and report your modifications on '`www/include/global.inc`' there.

Surely the status for that file would be correct in the new local repository, which you can then push.

The OP solved it differently:

> I used the `git rm` command and deleted the file from the index tree.
>   And I added the file again to the folder and made modifications and this time `git status` command showed the file as modified.
>   Somehow the ignore settings were removed when I used the `git rm` command.

Comment: I sorted out my problem. I used the git rm command and deleted the file from the index tree. And I added the file again to the folder and made modifications and this time git status command showed the file as modified. Somehow the ignore settings were removed when I used the git rm command. I am actually a newbie to git and know very little and am operating in the dark. I am planning to take some time and read the git innards properly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jai Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks. I am thankful I got this problem sorted out today. It was really important as production is waiting. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need to do is:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged www/include/global.inc
```

So git cease to ignore the file.